# jQuery math two float numbers

Tags: jquery, ajax, math

I try to math 2 float number and add them to ajax query. But didnt work. Here is my code:

```
    // All padejPremium_X is 225.00
    var amount = $("#padejPremium_2").val() / 100) * 2; // (225.00 / 100) * 2 = 4.5
    var data = {
        DueAmount0: $("#padejPremium_1").val() + 10.00,
        DueAmount1: $("#padejPremium_2").val() + amount,
        DueAmount2: $("#padejPremium_3").val() + amount,
        DueAmount3: $("#padejPremium_4").val() + amount,
```

I will be very glad if someone give a idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var amount = parseFloat($("#padejPremium_2").val()) / 100 * 2; `https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: `val()` returns a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just missing the `(` in first line. Check the below code:

```
var amount = ($("#padejPremium_2").val() / 100) * 2; // (225.00 / 100) * 2 = 4.5
var data = {
    DueAmount0: $("#padejPremium_1").val() + 10.00,
    DueAmount1: $("#padejPremium_2").val() + amount,
    DueAmount2: $("#padejPremium_3").val() + amount
    }
    console.log(data);
```

Check the demo here:

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/04vfok75/) (check in console)